# Why doesn't TPath.GetAttributes return faSymLink for my symbolic link?

Tags: delphi, winapi, file-io, delphi-11-alexandria

`TFile.IntegerToFileAttributes` does not return `TFileAttribute.faSymLink` for me.

I tried using `TPath.GetAttributes` on a symbolic link to another directory.

I was expecting that the returned attributes would contain `TFileAttribute.faSymLink`.

`TPath.GetAttributes` calls `TFile.DoGetAttributes` which calls `TFile.IntegerToFileAttributes` on the result of `FileGetAttr`. `FileGetAttr` returns $410 (`FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT or FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY`) but `IntegerToFileAttributes` checks for `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVICE` to include `TFileAttribute.faSymLink` instead of `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT`. Is this a bug?

Comment: No: strictly speaking an [NTFS reparse point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_reparse_point) is not always/necessarily a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_links#Types).

Comment: But does the used `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVICE` ever mark a symbolic link? [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-attribute-constants) says it is reserved. Furthermore if the `FollowLink` parameter of `FileGetAttr` is set the function does in fact check against $400 (the constant is even called `faSymLink` as well). [Here](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.SysUtils.FileGetAttr) it says, that `FollowLink` is used for symbolic links. If it's not a bug but intended then it's at least inconsistent.

Comment: When `FollowLink` is true (the default), the result is relative to the target of the symlink, not for the symlink itself.

Comment: I was just mentioning, that inside `FileGetAttr`, for `FollowLink` to work with symbolic links the attribute flags are checked against $400, which is called `faSymLink` here but really represents the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT` flag. On the other hand `TFile.IntegerToFileAttributes` does not check against this flag but rather the reserved `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVICE`. Why is that?